# mozilla npapi plugin resize issue

Tags: windows, firefox, npapi, browser-plugin

When Firefox is resized the embedded mfc application (which uses apapi plugin for embeddation) is unable to fit in the resize window (firefox).

Till 17.0 version the issue was not there, post 17.0 this issue is reproducible.

Whenever resized WM_PAINT (message 15 ) is send to application The code flow (pre 18.0 firefox version to embedded application):

1. `pWnd->WindowProc(nMsg, wParam, lParam)`
2. `CWnd::WindowProc ---> if (!OnWndMsg(message, wParam, lParam, &lResult))`
       `lResult = DefWindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);`
3. This in turn calls `CView::OnPaint()`

Now from 18.0, I am unable to get any call to my application.

Let me know for further clarification.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) for more details.

Comment: Need more information... is SetWindow being called? Did you get the HWND? How are you subclassing the window? etc

Comment: Please avoid or at least point out cross-posting so efforts to help are not duplicated. Cross-posted on bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=896358